# Flex - Custom tooltip style for a single component

Tags: css, apache-flex, halo

How can we customize the background and font color of a *single instance* of a tooltip for one component? (Without changing all tooltips in the application.)

This is needed for the HALO component set (4.1 SDK), not Spark (css methods preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a named style, using styles that are applicable to the [ToolTip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/ToolTip.html#styleSummary) component; and when you create the ToolTip specify that style.

You can read these instructions for [customizing a ToolTip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7ff6.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7ff4).

Basically, listen to the toolTipShown event and set the styleName on the toolTip.